# Displaying line breaks from SQL in a bound label

Tags: asp.net

I'm having issues either displaying new line characters pulled from a SQL database into a `DataList` or similar control.  I'm preserving the characters when I insert them, and a quick `SELECT` statement shows line breaks.  However, when I pull data into a datalist, it shows spaces rather than new lines.  Code currently looks like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="CommentLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comment").ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />") %>' />
```

I've seen recommendations for using `Server.HTMLEncode` as well, and I'd like to, however none with an example on using it in such a situation, and my attempts at it have yielded no visible difference, like:

```
<asp:Label ID="CommentLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Server.HTMLEncode(Eval("Comment").ToString()).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />") %>' />
```

Am I missing some piece of the puzzle here?

EDIT: new lines are created via Enter inside a multiline textbox. I'm not sure if that makes a different character than what's included in `Environment.Newline` or not, but generated HTML shows `<span>` tags with the appropriate line breaks inside, but no `<br />` tags, so I'm guessing that it's different.  If so, what's the appropriate character to be replacing?

EDIT2: code for the item template

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr style="font-weight:bold">
        <td>
            Comment ID: <asp:Label ID="CommentIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CommentID") %>' />
            Commenter: <asp:Label ID="CommenterLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>' />
            Comment Date: <asp:Label ID="DateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="CommentLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("Comment")).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Have you verified what is the HTML that your code is generating?

Comment: It's seeing line breaks, but they aren't replaced with <br />.  I'm guessing it's because the breaks are made with the enter key in a textbox earlier, and the character generated isn't included in `Environment.NewLine`, thus making the `.Replace` miss.

Comment: Apparently the problem is that the string that you are retrieving from the database doesn't have new lines characters in the format that `Environment.NewLine` represents. May be you can copy the string retrieved or look at its content in the Debugger to see what characters are representing the NewLine. May be there aren't at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Augustin Meriles said in his comment, the issue lies in the fact that hitting enter inside a multiline textbox does not use a new line character included in `Environment.NewLine`.  Some looking into it revealed that it was writing in `vbCr` and `vbLf` as opposed to using `vbCrLf`.  Knowing that, changing my replace methods fixed it.

```
<asp:Label ID="CommentLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("Comment")).Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, vbCrLf).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />") %>' />
```

This achieved a recognized and uniform line break throughout the view.

Answer (score 0):

Watch the html code generated by your page, you will see something like this:

```
<table id="GridView1">
<tr>
<td>
hello<br/>hello
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

but if you convert the gridviews (or other controls) column type to template field you will see something like this:

```
<table id="GridView1">
<tr>
<td>
 <span id="GridView1_Label1_0">hello <br/>hello</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And now there are line breaks in it! So all in all, you only have to convert your columns to template fields.